# Getting Error here in web scraping using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Running this code but dont know why its shoeing error??

```
#extracting text from all the url
url_id=1
for i in range(0,len(df)):
 
   j=df.iloc[i].values
   
   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}#giving user access
   page=requests.get(j[0],headers=headers)#loading text in url
   soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')#parsing url text
   content=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'td-post-content'})#extracting only text part
   content=content[0].text.replace('\xa0',"  ").replace('\n',"  ")#replace end line symbol with space 
   title=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'entry-title'})#extracting title of website
   title=title[16].text.replace('\n',"  ").replace('/',"")
   text=title+ '.' +content#merging title and content text
   text=np.array(text)#converting to array form
   text.reshape(1,-1)#changing shape to 1d 
   df1=pd.Series(text)#creating series data frame
   b=str(url_id)+"."+'txt'#name of the text file
  # with open(b, 'a') as f:#creating text file 
   # df1.to_csv(f, line_terminator=',', index=False, header=False)
  # files.download(b)#downloading text file
   url_id+=1
```

here its showing as

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <cell line: 3>()
      9 soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')#parsing url text
     10 content=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'td-post-content'})#extracting only text part
---> 11 content=content[0].text.replace('\xa0',"  ").replace('\n',"  ")#replace end line symbol with space 
     12 title=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'entry-title'})#extracting title of website
     13 title=title[16].text.replace('\n',"  ").replace('/',"")

IndexError: list index out of range
```

not able to understand why???
help with this problem..

Comment: Your list is empty and you can't use `[0]` on `content`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> not able to understand why???

It looks like the html in `page` does not contain any tags with `td-post-content` class, so the `content` returned in line 10 is an empty ResultSet (something like `[]`), which is why the `content[0]` part of line 11 raises an `IndexError`. You can simply skip URLs that don't have this class in the fetched html:

```py
   content=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'td-post-content'})#extracting only text part
   if not content: 
      print('NO .td-post-content CONTENT FROM', j[0])
      continue ## <--- SKIP REST OF LOOP TO NEXT URL'S LOOP
   content=content[0].text.replace('\xa0',"  ").replace('\n',"  ")#replace end line symbol with space
```

---

If you want to keep track of pages that were skipped, you can use something like [this error logger](https://pastebin.com/cxGH50Mc) instead of just printing

```py
## ADD TO THE BEGINNING OF YOUR CODE:
# import os
# def logError_scrapes... ## PASTE FUNCTION DEFINITION FROM https://pastebin.com/cxGH50Mc

## INSIDE THE LOOP:
   if not content:
      # print('NO .td-post-content CONTENT FROM', j[0])
      logError_scrapes(
           logId=f'row_{i}-url_{url_id}', url=j[0], req=page
         , msg='No .td-post-content in fetched html'
         # , conf={'saveHtml': True} # to save html to file (instead of csv column)

         # if you want to save prettified html in csv column:
         # , rSoup=soup , conf={'saveHtml': True, 'minify': False} 
      )
      continue ## <--- SKIP REST OF LOOP TO NEXT URL'S LOOP
```

(By default, the error log gets saved to "scrape_fails.csv", but you can modify this default in the function or specify another file path through the `conf` argument [with key `'errLogFp'`].)

The logfile contents look something like [image: samplop]

If `reqStatus` doesn't have `200 OK`, that means something went wrong with `requests.get` [in line 8 of your code]; you can decide what to do next based on the [response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses) [like, for 403 you might need better headers, with 503 you might just need to try again later, etc].

However, if it *is* `200 OK` then that might mean that the fetched html is just different from what you were expecting. In that case, you should open the html file in a code editor [if you didn't use the `saveHtml` option, copy the html from the last column (`htmlString`) to a .html file]; then you can see what the html looks like and whether the data you want is in a different format from expected, or missing entirely...

---

Btw, there is another line in your code with potential for index error

```py
   title=title[16].text.replace('\n',"  ").replace('/',"")
```

You could do the same for that line - precede it with `if not title[16:]....continue` (with `msg='page does not have .entry-title[16]'` if you're logging).

(You could also wrap everything in the loop in a `try` block and log error in the `except` block....)